# JSF Component for Diff Tool

Tags: jsf, diff

Is there a jsf component which displays the diff of two Java/Html/Php etc. source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such component comes to mind.

But it's *basically* a matter of two `<h:inputTextarea>` components of the same dimensions next to each other and running [some JavaScript Diff library](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20diff) on both, such as [PrettyDiff](http://prettydiff.com/).